# Node JS: Twich Bot messages are only displayed if on the own channel

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to make a bot that reacts to The User Messages. My Problem is, that the Messages the Bot sends appear in the Console, but not in the Twich Chat. In the Twich chat the Messages are only displayed on the Bots Channel.

Im Using tmi.js

My Code:

```
const tmi = require("tmi.js");

var config = require('./config');
const { channels } = require("./config");

const twitch_client = new tmi.client(config);

twitch_client.connect();

grussFormen = [
    'Hi',
    'Hallo',
    'Guten Tag',
    'Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren',
    'Sehr geehrter Herr',
    'Sehr geehrte Frau',
    'Grüß dich',
    'Grüß Sie',
    'Grüezi',
    'Hey',
    'Hej',
    'Moin',
    'Servus',
    'Na?',
    'Was geht?'
];

verabschiedungen = [
    'Mit freundlichen Grüßen',
    'Viele Grüße',
    'Liebe Grüße',
    'Alles Liebe',
    'Bis dann',
    'Bis später',
    'Bis morgen',
    'Mach’s gut',
    'Tschüss',
    'Tschüssi',
    'Tschü’',
    'Schönen Tag noch',
    'Schönen Abend noch',
    'Ciao',
    'Tschau',
    'Tschaui',
    'Wir sehen uns!',
]

twitch_client.on('connected', (address, port) =>{
    // twitch_client.action('derNiklaas', 'Restarted');
});

twitch_client.on('chat', (channel, user, message, self) =>{

    //In lowercase and withour Spaces
    // analysingMessage = message.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, '');
    
    //In lowercase
    analysingMessage = message.toLowerCase();
    
    //Nach Begrüßungs Formeln suchen
    for (let item of grussFormen) {
        if (analysingMessage.includes(' ' + item.toLowerCase()) || analysingMessage.includes(item.toLowerCase() + ' ') || analysingMessage == item.toLowerCase()){
            twitch_client.action(channel, item + ' @' + user.username, (err) =>{
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    //Nach Verabschiedungen suchen
    for (let item of verabschiedungen) {
        if (analysingMessage.includes(' ' + item.toLowerCase()) || analysingMessage.includes(item.toLowerCase() + ' ') || analysingMessage == item.toLowerCase()){
            twitch_client.action(channel, item + ' @' + user.username, (err) =>{
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
        }
    }
    
});
```

config.js (The Comments are not in:

```
module.exports = {
    options: {
         debug: true
    },
    connection: {
        reconnect: true,
        secure: true,
        timeout: 180000,
        reconnectDecay: 1.4,
        reconnectInterval: 1000,
    },
    identity: {
        username: 'isi_ko_bot',
        password: 'I Removed my Password here :D'
    },
    channels: [
        'derNiklaas'    // A Channel I Whatch
        // 'isi_ko_bot' // The Bots Channel
        // 'isi_kohd'   // My Channel
    ]
}
```

Screenshot of the Console:
[image: Here should be a Screenshot of the Console]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you're trying to make it so that the bot react to a specific message, to do this use the following format.

```js
if (message.startsWith("message you want the bot to react to")) {
//what you want the bot to do 
}
```

**example:**

```js
if (message.startsWith("hello")) {

client.say (channel, "Hello There!")

}
```